# Cannot deploy squid to Subsquid dashboard

Tags: subsquid, docker

I've recently been playing around with making and deploying my own squid. I keep getting a deploy_error on the website after deploying my squid via CLI. Visiting my URL I get the message below.

[image]

I've attached my `package.json`, `docker file`, and the `docker build .`

I'm using a Raspberry Pi4 and running node v16.14.2 and npm v8.6.0

Running the command npx sqd squid tail app-name@one returns the message:

```
{
  name: Error,
  message: HTTP request failed,
  errors: [],
  label: SERVER_ERROR
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "kusama-balances",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf lib && tsc",
    "init": "node db/init.js",
    "db:migrate": "npx sqd db migrate",
    "schema:reset": "",
    "processor:migrate": "echo skip",
    "processor:start": "node lib/processor.js",
        "processor:docker-run": "bash scripts/docker-run.sh",
        "query-node:start": "squid-graphql-server",
        "lint": "npm run lint:prod -- --fix",
        "lint:prod": "eslint . --ext .ts --ignore-path .gitignore --max-warnings 0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@subsquid/archive-registry": "^0.0.5",
        "@subsquid/cli": "^0.2.1",
        "@subsquid/graphql-server": "^0.1.5",
        "@subsquid/ss58": "^0.1.0",
        "@subsquid/substrate-processor": "^0.6.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "pg": "^8.7.3",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.41"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@subsquid/substrate-metadata-explorer": "^0.0.7",
        "@subsquid/substrate-typegen": "^0.4.1",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
        "typescript": "~4.6.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-type-graphql": "^0.3.2"
      }
    }
```

**DOCKER FILE**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS node

FROM node AS node-with-gyp
RUN apk add g++ make python3

FROM node-with-gyp AS builder
WORKDIR /squid
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci
ADD tsconfig.json .
ADD src src
RUN npm run build

FROM node-with-gyp AS deps
WORKDIR /squid
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci --production

FROM node AS squid
WORKDIR /squid
COPY --from=deps /squid/package.json .
COPY --from=deps /squid/package-lock.json .
COPY --from=deps /squid/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=builder /squid/lib lib
ADD db db
ADD schema.graphql .
# TODO: use shorter PROMETHEUS_PORT
ENV PROCESSOR_PROMETHEUS_PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 4000


FROM squid AS processor
CMD ["npm", "run", "processor:start"]


FROM squid AS query-node
CMD ["npm", "run", "query-node:start"]
```

**running the terminal command:**

```
sudo docker build . -t squid-template:latest --no-cache



Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.088MB
Step 1/31 : FROM node:16-alpine AS node
 ---> 230f2ea7123d
Step 2/31 : FROM node AS node-with-gyp
 ---> 230f2ea7123d
Step 3/31 : RUN apk add g++ make python3
 ---> Running in 2432453f6554
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/24) Installing binutils (2.37-r3)
(2/24) Installing libgomp (10.3.1_git20211027-r0)
(3/24) Installing libatomic (10.3.1_git20211027-r0)
(4/24) Installing libgphobos (10.3.1_git20211027-r0)
(5/24) Installing gmp (6.2.1-r1)
(6/24) Installing isl22 (0.22-r0)
(7/24) Installing mpfr4 (4.1.0-r0)
(8/24) Installing mpc1 (1.2.1-r0)
(9/24) Installing gcc (10.3.1_git20211027-r0)
(10/24) Installing musl-dev (1.2.2-r7)
(11/24) Installing libc-dev (0.7.2-r3)
(12/24) Installing g++ (10.3.1_git20211027-r0)
(13/24) Installing make (4.3-r0)
(14/24) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r1)
(15/24) Installing expat (2.4.7-r0)
(16/24) Installing libffi (3.4.2-r1)
(17/24) Installing gdbm (1.22-r0)
(18/24) Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r1)
(19/24) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r1)
(20/24) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(21/24) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(22/24) Installing readline (8.1.1-r0)
(23/24) Installing sqlite-libs (3.36.0-r0)
(24/24) Installing python3 (3.9.7-r4)
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r5.trigger
OK: 237 MiB in 40 packages
Removing intermediate container 2432453f6554
 ---> 53a776507944
Step 4/31 : FROM node-with-gyp AS builder
 ---> 53a776507944
Step 5/31 : WORKDIR /squid
 ---> Running in 73a44b66c69b
Removing intermediate container 73a44b66c69b
 ---> b48edef8654c
Step 6/31 : ADD package.json .
 ---> ccf828502935
Step 7/31 : ADD package-lock.json .
 ---> e7e6e0c0ff7e
Step 8/31 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in c187bfd9b9aa
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated cli-ux@5.6.7: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated lru-cache@7.7.1: Please update to latest patch version to fix memory leak https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/issues/227
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 930 packages, and audited 931 packages in 4m

111 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 5 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 8.8.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.8.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.8.0` to update!
npm notice
Removing intermediate container c187bfd9b9aa
 ---> 75a6aa00a9dd
Step 9/31 : ADD tsconfig.json .
 ---> 5df2d8ef6b7c
Step 10/31 : ADD src src
 ---> 729f5b825ab6
Step 11/31 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in a56e1580dfcb

> build
> rm -rf lib && tsc

Removing intermediate container a56e1580dfcb
 ---> 246de23625c8
Step 12/31 : FROM node-with-gyp AS deps
 ---> 53a776507944
Step 13/31 : WORKDIR /squid
 ---> Running in a35c3b2212d8
Removing intermediate container a35c3b2212d8
 ---> df213bd4e7e4
Step 14/31 : ADD package.json .
 ---> ec17482b4f85
Step 15/31 : ADD package-lock.json .
 ---> 00523b03480a
Step 16/31 : RUN npm ci --production
 ---> Running in 694971c7c74b
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated cli-ux@5.6.7: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated lru-cache@7.7.1: Please update to latest patch version to fix memory leak https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/issues/227
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 793 packages, and audited 794 packages in 4m

63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 5 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 8.8.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.8.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.8.0` to update!
npm notice
Removing intermediate container 694971c7c74b
 ---> 1c0b3fefeecc
Step 17/31 : FROM node AS squid
 ---> 230f2ea7123d
Step 18/31 : WORKDIR /squid
 ---> Running in 6f56090d20b0
Removing intermediate container 6f56090d20b0
 ---> df951ee65111
Step 19/31 : COPY --from=deps /squid/package.json .
 ---> 1531926eb9a2
Step 20/31 : COPY --from=deps /squid/package-lock.json .
 ---> 8815d07f5a5a
Step 21/31 : COPY --from=deps /squid/node_modules node_modules
 ---> 94bcc6b6783b
Step 22/31 : COPY --from=builder /squid/lib lib
 ---> f9e2c03f90b6
Step 23/31 : ADD db db
 ---> e66cc42f967c
Step 24/31 : ADD schema.graphql .
 ---> 52dd9bfab5a0
Step 25/31 : ENV PROCESSOR_PROMETHEUS_PORT 3000
 ---> Running in 43e8f9fb49fa
Removing intermediate container 43e8f9fb49fa
 ---> 0e002c90bad2
Step 26/31 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in c09884e86e87
Removing intermediate container c09884e86e87
 ---> 6b2911209368
Step 27/31 : EXPOSE 4000
 ---> Running in 222ec7dfffd4
Removing intermediate container 222ec7dfffd4
 ---> 68c23cc3c950
Step 28/31 : FROM squid AS processor
 ---> 68c23cc3c950
Step 29/31 : CMD ["npm", "run", "processor:start"]
 ---> Running in 6c6dfd10b961
Removing intermediate container 6c6dfd10b961
 ---> db98e6f855df
Step 30/31 : FROM squid AS query-node
 ---> 68c23cc3c950
Step 31/31 : CMD ["npm", "run", "query-node:start"]
 ---> Running in 7d278cef25e7
Removing intermediate container 7d278cef25e7
 ---> 064d789f2255
Successfully built 064d789f2255
Successfully tagged squid-template:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in not pushing all files to github. There were some `.model` files which prevented the build from completing outside of my local environment.
-_-